# Increment value on MySQLi Update

Tags: php, mysqli

Simply trying to add points to an existing value in a column named 'Points'. I've read a few articles that suggest the beneath, but it's not working for me. Perhaps because I'm using mysqli rather than mysql? Any thoughts? The if statement works fine.

```
if (!empty($m1A) && ($r1A == 0)) {
    // Rewards pts
    $query = "UPDATE users SET Points=Points+3 WHERE 1A='$m1A'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    // Record reward of pts
    $query1 = "UPDATE rounds SET 1A = 1";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
}
```

Comment: What does mysqi_error() say?

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not going through even with jeroen's fix. What kind of debugging should I try?

Comment: Put this at the top of your script to have mysqli throw an exception if something goes wrong: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: 1A is set to varchar, the value is "mex".

Comment: Points = integer (value = 1); rounds = integer (value = 0); 1A = varchar (value = mex)

Comment: @jeroen - I added your mysqli_report and got this error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Unknown column 'bra' in 'where clause'' in C:\jpdio\026 - World Cup\refresh.php:66 Stack trace: #0 C:\jpdio\026 - World Cup\refresh.php(66): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'UPDATE users SE...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\jpdio\026 - World Cup\refresh.php on line 66

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your column name starts with a number, you have to quote it in backticks:

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET Points=Points+3 WHERE `1A`=$m1A";
```

and:

```
$query1 = "UPDATE rounds SET `1A` = 1";
```

And I would recommend using a prepared statement with bound parameters to avoid sql injection problems.

**Edit:** If your `1A` column is not an integer column and the values are strings, you need to quote them.

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET Points=Points+3 WHERE `1A`='$m1A'";
                                                      ^    ^
```

Although that problem would be solved automatically with a prepared statement...

Comment: Thanks a ton! I'll take some time and learn more about prepared statements to avoid time wasters like these.

Comment: @JamesPatrick I was just reading the PHP Manual about prepared statements. https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php