# PDO Select then Update

Tags: php, pdo

Building a tool that first pulls a sim number, then marks it as taken. The first part is working great and is being served to my page with ajax. The second part doesn't seem to want to work.

```
include_once 'inc/db_connect.php';

$stmt = $db->query('SELECT sim FROM p2p WHERE taken = 0 ORDER by id ASC LIMIT 1');
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $result = $row['sim'];
}

echo json_encode($result);

$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE p2p SET taken = 1 WHERE sim = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $result);
$stmt->execute();
```

Any ideas!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of this [`bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) that is [**MySQLi_***](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) syntax and you're using [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

`fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

---

- Use PDO's [`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) function

Those two APIs do not mix.

If that doesn't work, use [`bindValue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. That will signal the error.

---

*An insight*

I've noticed in [**a previous question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24175046/) you posted, that you are using `mysqli_*` functions to connect to your database with.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

If that is still the case, then you cannot mix PDO with `mysqli_` in any way, shape or form.

- Those MySQL APIs do not intermix with each other.
- Consult: **http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php**

Comment: Hi Fred thanks for the insights. I'm going to take some time and read through what api I want to use. Cheers.