# Incrementing Int value using UPDATE MySqli PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, mysqli

I am new to SQL and PHP, and I am trying to create a basic 'like' system where a int count is kept in the db for every time the like button is pressed. I've looked online but can't seem to spot out what I have done wrong. It works fine for creating new records, however cannot seem to increment the value for preexisting entries. I'm sure it's small.

```
<form action="post-like.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="post1"></input>
  <button type="Submit">Like!</button>
</form>


// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$postid = $_POST['post_id'];
$sqlcheck = "SELECT * FROM  `likes`WHERE  `postid` =  '$postid'LIMIT 0 , 30";
$checkpost = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlcheck);
$check_post = mysqli_fetch_row($checkpost);

if ($check_post > 0) {
    $sqlike = ("UPDATE likes SET postlikes = postlikes + 1 WHERE postid = '".$postid."'");
    echo "<script>alert('" . $postid . "');</script>";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqllike)) {
        echo "New like created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

} else {
    $sqlnewpost = "INSERT INTO  `tentoesdown`.`likes` (`postid` ,`postlikes`)VALUES ('$postid',  '1');";
    echo "<script>alert('ya2');</script>";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlnewpost)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
```

[image: database table 'likes']

[image]

Can't find this error!

Comment: Is the first echo printing a valid postid? can you add an image of the table structure?

Comment: @altoids Yes, all three echoes return. I've added an image of the structure - is that what you were looking for? Thanks.

Comment: where are you executing the update? you're assigning $sqlike the query but not executing it.

Comment: @altoids Thanks. Got it. :)

Comment: how did you solve it?

Comment: @altoids I was missing the if/else statement which executes the query and verifies that the like was submitted. Thanks for the help!

Comment: FYI this is not how to do this sort of thing. First, SQL databases should use numeric primary key columns; MySQL even has the `SERIAL` column shorthand for this purpose. Second, what happens when you replace your "hidden" form input with this value? `foobar' OR 'foo'='foo`

Comment: do visit this post which has an easy way to update....   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175046/increment-value-on-mysqli-update

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
if ($check_post > 0) {
```

to:

```
if ( (count($check_post) > 0 ) {
```

`mysqli_fetch_row` will always return an array, not a number.